# What to do if a book is in peer review for 9 months without a decision?

Tags: publications, peer-review

If a book (full-text research monograph) has been under peer review for 9 months and there is still no decision, what should I do? Would it be counterproductive to press the editor to make a decision?

Comment: Did you submit the book proposal just to one publisher?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes.

Comment: Unless you already signed a contract, my suggestion is to send the book to at least one more publisher and inquire from thr current one about the status of the submission and when to expect a decision.

Comment: Yes, as Moishe says, book proposals are typically sent to several publishers at once. My understanding is that you then sort of play them off each other to speed up the process.

Comment: How much communication have you had with the publisher over those 9 months? Have you been asked for revisions, etc?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I’ve already signed the contract.

Comment: @Buffy No revision ask yet.

Comment: @Dawn I don't think that applies when the manuscript is sent out for peer review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I am a mathematician and I will answer from the math perspective, more precisely, publishing research monographs (rather than textbooks). Here are my thoughts after your comments (you already signed a contract and, thus, referees are looking at the entire book) brought some clarity:

The time-length of peer-review depends on many parameters, such as the length of the book, the degree of difficulty of the text and, most importantly, how seriously referees approach their job. Some referees do very superficial reading, limiting themselves to reading the introduction and browsing through the rest of the book. Their reports usually do not take much time to write. In contrast, other referees read carefully, find mistakes, make useful suggestions on organizing the material, etc.

I published two (math) research monographs and  have one more under revision (after referee reports). For all three books I had both types of referees (one wrote nearly 100 pages worth of very useful and critical comments on a 600 page long manuscript). Accordingly, one year lag is not unreasonable. Still, I would be asking the publisher after 9 months about the status of reports. You cannot really "press" them though. But if, for instance, they say that one of the referees simply stopped responding, you can suggest looking for an alternative referee.  You can also ask to see the reports submitted so far (so that you can start making at least **some** revisions).

Comment: Yeah, it’s a research monograph.